# How do you get shortcode content and other templates.php file content or ACF content indexed in the normal wordpress search feature using search.php

Tags: wordpress, templates, search, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I've been trying to conduct some research on this issue,

So building a shortcode for example lets say I have this function

```
function example_shortcode($content, $atts){

    $disclaimer = $atts['disclaimer'];

    return "<div>$disclaimer</div>";

}

add_shortcode("example_shortcode","example_shortcode");
```

buy having the

```
$content //variable passed to the example_shortcode();
```

This sort of works for shortcodes as long as it is output by the standard

```
the_content(); //function through the wordpress wysiwyg
```

But lets say I call the function into a custom-template.php file and add that template to the page editor attributes for WordPress instead of using the WYSIWYG, then the shortcode content wont appear when doing a search on the front end of the site. To me I feel like wordpress should process this this more intelligently in the future especially since using custom templates loaded through wordpress.But for example

```
i.e. example.com/?s=test
```

What concept do I need to start understanding next here, I know if the shortcode is processed through the_content(); function it will sort of work as mentioned earlier,

But really the second part of my question, is just dealing with custom-template.php files using Advanced Custom Fields being output into custom_functions(); then being called into custom-templates.php which are then being loaded through the page attributes of the wordpress page editor, my content and everything works just doesnt show up in search results on wordpress frontend site itself?

I've searched the internet for this issue many times, doesn't seem like many people care about this issue, as I can't find much research or the research is tough to find, or I'm searching incorrectly.

Can anyone start pointing me in the right direction, and new tips on research for this topic.

Thank you all for any comments and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ive conducted countless hours of research, along with the Plugin Author of Relevanssi Better Search for Wordpress.

So I wanted to share the solutions here.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-not-including-php-hard-coded-content/#post-14432554

This Stack Overflow question is also related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67440133/how-do-you-get-a-custom-template-php-file-with-content-in-wordpress-page-attribu)