# How do you get a custom template.php file with content in wordpress page attribute setting, to have content searchable on the site via search.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, search

Hi I am trying to understand something I feel is rather complex.

Lets say I create a custom template file and add it to the page attributes of the Wordpress page editor to use. In that template file I am echo ing out some PHP functions and other content that is not stored in the database.

Using the custom template file, does not go through the_content() function either.

So on the front end of the site, I try to search exact phrases I have loaded via a custom template file and it will not return any results.

However any content I have loaded traditionally though TinyMCS Wysiwyg utilizing the_content() function in the default template will show and work fine when doing a search on the front end of the site.

Any help would be appreciate or any ideas for additional research would be helpful to thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ive conducted countless hours of research, along with the Plugin Author of Relevanssi Better Search for Wordpress.

So I wanted to share the solutions here.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-not-including-php-hard-coded-content/#post-14432554

This Stack Overflow question is also related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427604/how-do-you-get-shortcode-content-and-other-templates-php-file-content-or-acf-con/67512634#67512634)